# Strange cleanup behaviour with FOR UPDATE

Tags: sql-update, postgresql-9.3, mvcc

I wonder if xmax value should not be set to zero after UPDATE operation even if FOR UPDATE clause is used in a subquery?

I have created test table:

```
CREATE TABLE def.dummy
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nazwa text,
  CONSTRAINT pk_dummy PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

and inserted some values:

```
INSERT INTO def.dummy(
            nazwa)
    VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3');
```

Now when I'm trying to do UPDATE with subquery:

```
UPDATE def.dummy AS sp
SET nazwa = 'changed' FROM
(SELECT id, nazwa, xmax, xmin
 FROM def.dummy
          WHERE id=1
AND xmax = 0
LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) AS get_set
WHERE get_set.id = sp.id;
RETURNING sp.*;
```

After commiting transaction xmax value doesn't reset to 0 but stays as:
[image: xmax after update]

Is it correct behaviour? If yes, why xmax isn't set to zero after operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that behavior is correct.  Xmax is also used for lockers, not only updaters, and it's up to the reader of the value to ensure that it ignores a non-zero value when the LOCK bits are set in t_infomask (see `src/include/access/htup_details.h` for values of the bits in t_infomask).  You can't access t_infomask from the regular SQL interface though, but see the `pageinspect` extension which gives you access to it.

Note that tuples can be locked by foreign key checks also, so it's not just `FOR UPDATE` that would cause nonzero values to appear in `Xmax`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. do you know maybe where can I find those informations? in documentation could not find anything about foreign key checks for instance.

Comment: I don't think we document this kind of thing; it would become a problem whenever we wanted to change the underlying representation in the future, because if we documented it, people would become dependent on a particular way of doing it.  Of course, you can always read the source code, which for PostgreSQL is pretty well documented.